'instagram_graph_user_profile' button is inactivate
enter image description here
i'm in the proccess of getting app review.
it says ' To use instaram_graph_user_media, you must include instagram_grpah_user_profile'
but in my dashboard, instagram_graph_user_profile button is inactivated. can't click !!
how can i make 'instagram_grpah_user_profile' button clickable ? enter image description here
i want to add user-profile to app review

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
